# Gulp-sass, ошибка поиска файла sass через include

Tags: gulp, sass

Дело банально в том, что таск sass при компиляции файла main.sass, в котором перечислены инклюды на другие sass-файлы, не компилирует в main.css, так как не может найти его.
[image]
То есть в main.css написано только такое:

```
@import "hello";
```

Ну а в hello написаны стандартные стили sass. 
Но если сохранить через Ctrl+S и "обновить" файл, то вотч запустит заного таск и всё благополучно скомпилируется.
Такое случается раз в 10 случаев, например, если просто жать Ctrl+S постоянно, но этим никто не занимается, однако ошибка появляется при реальной работе, что очень бесит.

Неужели сохранение файла hello (в котором я стили и пишу) происходит медленнее, чем отслеживание и компиляция sass в gulp?
Или, я не понимаю вообще, в чем может быть ошибка...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Неужели сохранение файла hello (в котором я стили и пишу) происходит
>   медленнее, чем отслеживание и компиляция sass в gulp? Или, я не
>   понимаю вообще, в чем может быть ошибка...

Именно так и происходит, причем данная проблема характерна в основном для win7 и HDD. При замене HDD на SDD все будет хорошо. Но менять диск из - за этого.... На мой взгляд не лучшая затея.
Есть как минимум 3 варианта исправления проблемы:
**1.** Предполагает хорошее понимание `Node.js`, а так же работу `node-sass` и `libsas`, которые собственно и выполняют компиляцию файлов.
Его суть заключается в написании собственного обработчика подключаемых файлов. Если заглянуть в [документацию](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass#importer--v200---experimental) к `node-sass`, то можно увидеть в объекте `options` ключ `importer`, который на самом деле является пользовательской функцией. Когда `LibSass` встречает директиву `@import`. Пользовательский импортер позволяет расширить движок `LibSass` как в синхронном, так и асинхронном режиме.
**2.** Этот способ основан на небольшом хаке в `watch` задаче и сводиться к добавлению таймера на выполнение `sass` задачи:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    watch('dev/scss/**/*.scss', function(event, cb) {
        setTimeout(function(){gulp.start('sass');},500) // задача выполниться через 500 миллисекунд и файл успеет сохраниться на диске
    });
});
```

Здесь я использовал плагин `gulp-watch`, но думаю и со стандартным галповским вотчером это прокатит.
**3.** Использование именно плагина `gulp-watch`, он принимает вторым параметром объект с опциями, среди которых есть задержка равная по умолчанию 10 миллисекундам.

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
        watch('dev/scss/**/*.scss', {readDelay: 100}, function(event, cb) {
            gulp.start('sass');
        });
    });
```

Подробнее можно почитать в [документации](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-watch#optionsreaddelay)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Второго способа вполне [хватило](http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2017/02/25/0001/0403/94611/11/f2d5b967ee.png), поставив задержку на 100 миллисекунд.